# jQuery append to table and td background color

Tags: jquery, colors, append, html-table

After appending a row to a table using jQuery I cannot change the background color of a td.

This is my code which WORKS and appends rows (with no attempts to change the color of the cell:

```
$( "#table_1 tbody" ).append( "<tr>" +
                              "<td>Some text</td>" +
                              "<td></td>" + 
                              "<td></td>" +
                              "<td>" + var1.val() + "</td>" +
                              "<td></td>" +
                              "</tr>" );
```

I want to grey out ALL the empty cells (i.e. those with `"<td></td>"`). I want them to have a grey background color so that the user knows they are empty or inactive. Can you please help out?

I've tried using the normal html tags to change td color but it doesn't work:
    `"<td style="background-color:#C0C0C0"></td>"`

I'm new to jQuery so I'm no really sure how achieve this. Thanks for the help!

Comment: No CSS classes? Maybe `.shaded: background-color: #C0C0C0` and `.addClass('shaded')` at the end of the append?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the Jquery manual, in specific:

http://api.jquery.com/empty-selector/

This gives the example

```
$("td:empty").css('background', 'rgb(255,220,200)');
```

Good luck

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with just CSS:

```
#table_1 td:empty {
    background-color: grey;
}
```

`:empty` isn't supported by IE8 and below, so you could use a CSS3 polyfill, or if you insist on jQuery, use jQuery's `:empty`:

```
$('#table_1 td:empty').addClass('empty');
```